# How do I add different post and get functions in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to find a way to add different post and get functions here on angularjs but I am not entirely sure where to put it under the app.js folder. Right now when I click post, it comes up with this code for every post button.

```
Post>> {"ID":"Graves Flats","Owner":"Graves","Address":"294 Te Aro, Wellington","Building Type":"Low rise apartments","Planned Date":"20/05/2016"}
```

But I am trying to figure out where can I can put the code in so when I click different post buttons, I get different data.

The code below shows up on every post button.

```
var Id = "Graves Flats"; 
var read = 'https://happybuildings.sim.vuw.ac.nz/api/woonker/building_dir.json';
var write = 'https://happybuildings.sim.vuw.ac.nz/api/woonker/update.building.json';
var sourceObj = { 
    "ID": Id,
    "Owner": "Graves",
    "Address": "294 Te Aro, Wellington",
    "Building Type": "Low rise apartments",
    "Planned Date": "20/05/2016"
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/nshTWxykbcwSiSdUabKk?p=preview

Comment: Your question is somewhat vague. I suggest you rephrase it a little bit. What do you mean by post? Where are you getting the building info from? Are you asking how to fetch data from the server, or how to filter an array of objects in JS? Or how to make a function that accepts and argument and gives you the property user clicks on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-repeat to print the divs and pass the corresponding $index to clickPost($index) function.

```
 <div ng-repeat="buildings in buildingsArray">
  <input type="submit" value="Cost Information" ng-click="clickPost($index)" />
  <input type="button" value="get" ng-click="clickGet($index)" />
  <br><br>
  {{feedback}}
</div>
```

And set a variable like $scope.showItems[$index]=true; on click.

And populate in the front end by

```
     <div ng-if="showItems[$index]==true">{{feedback}}</div>
```

This will also reduce your line of code.If you want to get different data for different post requests, you should not hardcode your source object which you are passing to the service call